# How to create dialog box by clicking on specific ListView items?

Tags: android, string, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a listview that has items added to it through other activities. My goal here is to make it where, when a **specific listview item is clicked**, it launches a **dialog box specific to the item clicked**.

Here's the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/inventoryListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:onClick="f">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>]
```

And here is the activity with the adapter

```
public class inventory extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ArrayList<String> items;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public static ListView inventoryListView;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setContentView(R.layout.inventory);

        inventoryListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.inventoryListView);

        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.inventory_list_view,items);
        inventoryListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
        updateInventory();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

The list is not populated because it can only be populated through other activities, and not the one that holds the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewholder pattern

[Example](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-viewholder-pattern-example/)

And in your `getView` method you can set onclicklistener to your view and launch your dialog for each row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use RecyclerView instead of Listview, it's more efficient in memory managing and performance.

as @ghost said, you can use ViewHolder Pattern and Push Your activity context to your view-holder and Adapter. You can simply put your clicking logic in your viewHolder (Inside of the Adapter).

Comment: Can i possibly get an example, or some pseudo code?